# How to Invoke Telnet communication using Java sockets?

Tags: java, telnet

I have an assignment to Implement telnet client and the server using TCP sockets, and execute commands such as ls, mkdir etc..

Question 1: 
I understand that we open socket on a specific port so that client and server can communicate using that socket. I tried this to pass the text messages, just like chat. But I would like to know if we can invoke telnet prompt and request the server to respond to client commands in this chat ?

Question 2: As understood, we can open a socket on ports > 1024 (example: 6525). But to implement Telnet protocol we use port 23. Can any one explain this implementation with a Java example.

Sorry, this may be a dumb question but im not good at networking concepts.

Comment: I sure hope no one has telnetd enabled anymore; this question is *very broad*.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Comment: You can use `ProcessBuilder` to invoke anything.  But please don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a school assignment, and your assignment is to implement it using sockets, then I assume that that you are supposed to actually work with sockets, not use a third-party library that solves the problem for you (which includes using telnet.exe via the Process class).

As telnet is a very simple, text-based protocol, this should be pretty easy using Socket, ServerSocket, and other classes in the [java.net package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html)

Comment: As advised, if i go to use telnet.exe in the Process class - i just realized that this would trigger a new window of the server and client. But im looking for the telnet prompt in the server and the client executions. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I guess you could use this:

https://www.webnms.com/cli/help/javadocs/cli/com/adventnet/telnet/TelnetSession.html

Comment: Hi, this seems to be useful for me. This seems to be a third-party jar that gives the TelnetSession java class. Could you ping me the link to download the jar that contains these supported classes ?

Comment: I found this standard apache package.                                                                                           http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/package-summary.html

Comment: You can download the jar somewhere in this page                                        http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/